# How to add keyBoardEvent for one particular button in actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder

I am newbie to actionscript. Just started learning it a couple of days ago. I am trying to add keyboardevents for a particular button. Here is what I have done so far.

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
public function f1():void
{
     // something
}
public function keyBoardListener(keyEvent:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if(keyEvent.keyCode==37)
        f1();

}
```

and in the button

```
<Lib:ManagedButton
     id = "MB"
     labelText = "MB"
     image = " ... "
     click="f1()"
     enabled = "false"
     stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyBoardListener);
 />
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Attribute name "stage.addEventListener" associated with an element type "Lib:ManagedButton" must be followed by the ' = ' character.
```

What I am trying to do is call the function f1() on pressing the left arrow key. I do not want this to happen for all the buttons on this page but only this button.

Comment: You're trying to run code in the mxml markup properties.  That's the reason for the error.  `stage.addEventListner` isn't a property, it's a call to a function.

Comment: Does `MangedButton` have a `keyDown` property you can specify?  If so, replace your call to `stage.addEventListener...` with `keyDown="keyBoardListener"`

Comment: @Brian These are the properties that ManagedButton has labelText:String, image:String. Just added keyDown:KeyboardEvent. Is that right?

Comment: Is `ManagedButton` your own custom class?  If so, you could put the listener code in there.  Do you want your `f1()` function to act only on the one button, or do you only want the arrow key to invoke it if that one button has focus?

Comment: @Brian ManagedButton is the same as s:Button except with some extra variables other than label,click etc . I want the arrow key to invoke when the button is on focus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're issue is the following:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,keyBoardListener);
```

You have that in the markup as a property  (it's expecting **param="value"**) and you're trying to call a code function.

You should create a class file for your button and add the listener and handler there. That way it will only run when the button has focus (which is what I'm assuming you want here).

```
package Lib {
    public class MyButton extends ManagedButton {
        public function MyButton(){
            this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,addedToStage,false,0,true);
            this.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE,removedFromStage,false,0,true);
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickEventHandler,false,0,true);
        }

        private function addedToStage(e:Event):void {
            this.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyBoardListener,false,0,true);
        }
        private function removedFromStage(e:Event):void {
            this.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyBoardListener,false);
        }

        [Bindable]
        public var clickHandler:Function;

        private function clickEventHandler(e:Event):void {
            if(clickHandler != null) clickHandler();
        }
        public function keyBoardListener(keyEvent:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            if(keyEvent.keyCode==37)
               if(clickHandler != null) clickHandler();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could just specify the value for `clickHandler` and have both your keyboard and click events launch it.  I don't really use FLEX, so someone may need to correct this, but I think this is what it would look like:

```
<Lib:MyButton
     id = "MB"
     labelText = "MB"
     image = " ... "
     enabled = "false"
     clickHandler = "f1()"
 />
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand this. My query is how to I relate this class to one particular button?. I am using many buttons declared by <Lib:ManagedButton /> each having a different values for the parameters.

Comment: I don't really use FLEX and am not too familiar with it's markup, but using the class file approach you'd have to actually reference that class **<Lib:MyButton>** instead of <Lib:ManagedButton>. Since I'm extending ManagedButton you can use all the same parameters and function of managed button, only difference is `MyButton` gives you the enter key functionality. The sample class in my answer is missing any imports that are needed.